# Accessing Value in Array Object with Generic Variable for Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I recognize that I can access the value of an object within an array by passing in the key name, like so:

```
   const batchNumValue = batchNumber[0]['MAX(batch_number) + 1'];
```

In my case I know the array will always contain exactly one object, with a single key/value pair, like so:

```
[{ 'MAX(batch_number) + 1' : 234 }]
```

That being the case, my question is, is there a way I can pass in a variable representing whatever that key name happens to be? Or does one have to always explicitly pass the key name, even in a situation like this?

Comment: please add an example of the data. btw, `'MAX(batch_number) + 1'` is a string.

Comment: I added the data above. Notice I'm getting the key as a string.

Comment: Why do you need an object with a single value instead of the value?

Comment: I don't "need" it, that's what I'm provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the values from the object and take the first item.

```js
const
    data = [{ 'MAX(batch_number) + 1' : 234 }],
    value = Object.values(data[0])[0];

console.log(value);
```